# How to write a condition use django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I write a if else statement to user but it not working. I get data form database use `Post.objects.get(sno = delpk)`. Then i writer a condition `request.user.username == Post.author`

```
def postdelapi(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
    delpk = request.POST['delpk']
    deletepost = Post.objects.get(sno = delpk)
    print(Post.author)
    if request.user.username == Post.author :
        deletepost.delete()
    else:
        HttpResponse('eroor')
 else:
    pass
 return redirect('home')
```

Comment: Querying is confusing for the beginners you need to read the documentation again ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

you need to compare `request.user.username` with `Post`'s object which is `deletepost`.

```py
if request.user.username == deletepost.author.username :
    deletepost.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

`Post.author` is most likely a `User` model **(check your models.py to confirm)** therefore should be compared with an equivalent `User` model which is `request.user` and not `request.user.username`:

```
if request.user == Post.author :
        deletepost.delete()
```

It is best if you compare the `User` instance instead of usernames in the case of users changing usernames and/or having duplicate usernames.